# Unable to login to IBM Bluemix through ssh in MAC

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud

I created a cluster and created my credentials, even with right credentials I am not able to log in to IBM bluemix hadoop cluster through ssh. 
I am using Mac

```
This is the error :
Last login: Thu Oct 19 16:36:27 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~$ sshtgt@bi-hadoop-prod-4067.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net
hghg@bi-hadoop-prod-4067.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ggfg@bi-hadoop-prod-4067.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net's password:
```

Comment: This may help. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/296008/is-there-possibility-to-connect-ibm-bluemix-over-s.html

Comment: Hadoop Cluster actually has SSH enabled. While it sits on the same GUI it's not CloudFoundry App.

Comment: @NeerajKumar That information is old now. Bluemix uses the Cloud Foundry Diego architecture now.

Answer (score 0):

That was an intermediate problem from IBM Bluemix Team. Got a temporary fix to solve the issue